# Django inbuilt loginview not working for Non Staff Users

Tags: django, authentication, model, logout

Hi I used a custom user model and django inbuilt authentication to login and logout

my urls.py is

```
from django.contrib.auth import views
.....
path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),]
```

It logs in for superuser credentials but for Non-Staff users it redirects to the login page again. So in order to find out the methods that are being called I tried to print the method names in the console to see what actually happens.
The below output I got for superuser:

```
dispatch
AnonymousUser
False
Dispatch Inside Class View
If Method
<bound method ProcessFormView.post of <django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView object at 0x7f165c1635b0>>
post
get_form_kwargs
{'initial': {}, 'prefix': None, 'data': <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['kWGzAoldTVleKHXezf98LX4RbgoOs4ZRO3RI2UjAIJoUYpmYPvQj52HztqZRE5mn'], 'username': ['surendersingh1995nov@gmail.com'], 'password': ['Singo*1995'], 'next': ['/profile/']}>, 'files': <MultiValueDict: {}>}
form_valid
<WSGIRequest: POST '/login/'>
surendersingh1995nov@gmail.com
get_redirect_url
```

First the dispatch method is called then dispatch method inside class View is called and so on.

Similarly for Non-Staff Users the output which I got is:

```
dispatch
AnonymousUser
False
Dispatch Inside Class View
If Method
<bound method ProcessFormView.post of <django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView object at 0x7f165c1a7940>>
post
get_form_kwargs
{'initial': {}, 'prefix': None, 'data': <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['6ex3Kzt2KNFrGYM3WAvwClLIQqu73vGlAlIcc5rpzBI7UGbNcQcHWqoq8A5afw3R'], 'username': ['arjunsingh1995nov@gmail.com'], 'password': ['Singo*1995'], 'next': ['/profile/']}>, 'files': <MultiValueDict: {}>}
get_context_data
get_context_data
get_redirect_url
```

The only difference is in this the form_valid method is not being called. But I cannot get exactly why this is not working. Please help me thanks.

Comment: by default only users with `is_active = True` can login. did you check it?

Comment: @AminMir Yes I check it. It is active for the Non Staff user which I used to login (arjunsingh1995nov@gmail.com)